# HTML5 File Reader failed to add multiple files and only adding one file from the list

Tags: html, filereader

I want to add three files simulteneously.Files with extension kml,kmz and csv.
When I select all three files and click open I get all three files in FileList. 
But only one file is getting added on map.If I add individual file i.e. one by one it works fine. reader onloadend event is fired 3 times.But all the time it adds only one of the three files.

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {        

 var files = evt.target.files; // FileList  

 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

     f = files[i];
     fileExtension = f.name.split('.').pop();    

 if(fileExtension != 'kml' && fileExtension !='kmz' && fileExtension != 'csv'){ 
      alert('Unsupported file type ' + f.type + '(' + fileExtension + ')');
        return;
      } 

var fileReaderkmlcsv = new FileReader();

fileReaderkmlcsv.readAsText(f); 
fileReaderkmlcsv.onloadend =loadend;  

} //- end for loop   } //handleFileSelect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was asynchronous code execution in javascript.
Here is the answer-
[Asynchronous execution in javascript any solution to control execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305423/asynchronous-execution-in-javascript-any-solution-to-control-execution/24307892#24307892)