# Asynchronous execution in javascript any solution to control execution?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I need a solution to control code execution in javascript.I want code on next line should not be executed unless the code on current line is completely executed.
Is there any solution?

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        alert("for");
        f = files[i];
        fileExtension = f.name.split('.').pop();    

        if(fileExtension != 'kml' && fileExtension !='kmz' && fileExtension != 'csv'){
            alert('Unsupported file type ' + f.type + '(' + fileExtension + ')');
            return;
        }       

        var fileReaderkmlcsv = new FileReader();                        
        fileReaderkmlcsv.onloadend = loadend;
        fileReaderkmlcsv.onerror = function(event) {
            alert("ERROR: " + event.target.error.code);
        };          
        fileReaderkmlcsv.readAsText(f);             
    } //- end for
} //handleFileSelect

function loadend(theFile) {
    alert("loadend");
    //code for processing my files
}
```

Comment: Javascript is inherently single threaded - code will only run in one place at a time and a function will fully execute before another event fires.  Have you got a specific issue with a particular bit of code?  Could you edit your question to include it?

Comment: Put it in the callback, or use a Promise.

Comment: Please post code here..so that we can can see what you are doing?

Comment: if you append some code, maybe we can help you with your missing callback mechanism

Comment: @JamesThorpe That's not true when one of the functions includes asynchronous execution. The next line will execute after the asynchronous operation is started, but won't wait for it to finish.

Comment: @@ Barmar statement is right

Comment: @Barmar yes, I should have clarified that a function "fully executing" includes the starting of anything asynchronous, and any subsequent events raised by the asynchronous code won't run until the original function has finished.

Comment: from file reader I am selecting/getting three files at a time with extension kml,kmz and csv in an arrayfiles[i]. and want to add on map.  But it is adding only one file among the three files. also executing the function loadend three times for three files. but altimately adding any one file.

Comment: Plz see the alert("for") and alert("loadend"); If I use this alert it works perfectly i.e. adds all the three files on map. But without alert i is incrementing before the execution of function loadend. I need a solution for this.

Comment: @ Barmar  - but with for loop how to use callback.

Comment: @ James Thorpe code added

Comment: @gauri just a note about comments, don't leave a space between @ and the username - SO doesn't generate a reply notification unless it's all one word - lucky I checked back :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `loadend` is running as soon as any one of the `FileReader`s has completed loading.  You'll need to redesign the code to wait for all 3 of them to finish, something like:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {    
    var files = evt.target.files;    
    var fileReaders = [];
    var loadCount = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        f = files[i];
        fileExtension = f.name.split('.').pop();   

        if(fileExtension != 'kml' && fileExtension !='kmz' && fileExtension != 'csv'){
            alert('Unsupported file type ' + f.type + '(' + fileExtension + ')');
            return;
        }

        function fileLoaded() {
            loadCount++;
            //Check if we've loaded all the files
            if (loadCount == files.length) {
                loadend(fileReaders);
            }
        }

        var fileReaderkmlcsv = new FileReader();                        
        fileReaderkmlcsv.onloadend = fileLoaded;
        fileReaderkmlcsv.onerror = function(event) {
            alert("ERROR: " + event.target.error.code);
        };          
        fileReaderkmlcsv.readAsText(f);
        fileReaders.push(fileReaderkmlcsv);
    }
  }

function loadend(files) {
    //files now contains an array of completed FileReader objects
}
```

Note that I don't have direct experience of the FileReader object itself - if onloadend doesn't fire if an error occurs, you'll need to put similar logic in the onerror event as well to make sure that the loadCount variable still gets incremented/checked etc.

Comment: I followed your code. Its working perfectly without any error. only i had to pass extension additionally.

Comment: But still confused about the concept of asynchronous execution.Was tht the problem or not. Because putting alert at every step was executing my code in proper way.What could be the reason?

Comment: It depends on how you were dealing with the actual results.  Having an alert in there would still prevent all the javascript from running while the alert was displayed, but in the background the fileReaders would still be processing the files and loading the results - by the time you've clicked ok on the alert, chances are they would all have finished